# Dependency Management in C with CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I have recently tried to make a few basic projects in C (using CMake), but one aspect I find very difficult is getting all the different things that I've been making to link together nicely. For example, I started off by making a data-structure library that has some of the basic data structures, along with functions to traverse them, etc., and a testing library that handles unit testing. In most new projects I make, I find that I need to include these two libraries, but I can't find an easy way to do it. I tried doing this using git submodule, and while that did work for the most part, whenever I updated any of the dependencies, updating the dependant seemed to be a nightmare. I've also had a look into the cmake package system; `find_package`, and related functions; but I can't seem to get that to work (at least when I want to install it in a custom directory, that is).

I was wondering if there is some sort of "standard" way that C programmers go about dealing with this, and what that may be. Is submodules the way to go? If so, is there a way I could do it cleanly, making sure that everything is always the right version?

Thanks in advance.